# Mirroring 2 different programs from right hand software to left handed software

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I am trying to mirror some geometries for a software based on right hand system reference to a left hand system reference ( Unity 3D). I am developing it in C# in both system with a program developed in Visual Studio in one side and a program developed in Unity3D in the other side. 2 different reference systems are explained in the following picture:

[image]

The code that I have is the following:

In right handed system is:

```
 private  List<Geometry> GetCADFromStation()
    {
        #region GetCADFromStationStep1
        List<Geometry> PartCollection = new List<Geometry>();


        foreach (GraphicComponent component in _ActiveStation.GraphicComponents)
        {
            if (component is Part)
            {
                Geometry p = new Geometry();
                p.Name = component.Name;
                p.TransX = component.Transform.X;
                p.TransY = component.Transform.Y;
                p.TransZ = component.Transform.Z;
                p.RotX = -component.Transform.RX;
                p.RotY = -component.Transform.RY;
                p.RotZ = -component.Transform.RZ;
                PartCollection.Add((Geometry)p);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        return PartCollection;
    }
```

The code that I have in Unity 3D is this:

```
 foreach (SerializeSocketUtils.Geometry geo in Pack.geometries)

        {

            float DegreesConverter = (float)(180 / Math.PI);
            Quaternion n;
            n = new Quaternion();


            GameObject value = GameObjectsInScene.Find(item => item.name == geo.Name );
            if (value != null)
            {
                n = ChangeRotationToUnity(new Vector3(((float)geo.RotX * DegreesConverter), ((float)geo.RotY * DegreesConverter), ((float)geo.RotZ * DegreesConverter)));

                value.transform.position = new Vector3(-(float)geo.TransX, (float)geo.TransY, (float)geo.TransZ);
                value.transform.rotation = n;

            }
```

The important function that I have in the unity side is ChangeRotationToUnity() that seems like this:

```
  Quaternion ChangeRotationToUnity(Vector3 rotation)
{
    Vector3 flippedRotation = new Vector3(rotation.x, -rotation.y, -rotation.z);
    Quaternion qx = new Quaternion();
    Quaternion qy = new Quaternion();
    Quaternion qz = new Quaternion();
    Quaternion qq = new Quaternion();
    qx = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flippedRotation.x, Vector3.right);
    qy = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flippedRotation.y, Vector3.up);
    qz = Quaternion.AngleAxis(flippedRotation.z, Vector3.forward);
    qq = qz * qy * qx;
    return qq;
}
```

This functions is based on this [post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/right-hand-to-left-handed-conversions.80679/) and in this [post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/349800-convert-rotations-from-right-hand-to-left-hand/)

Despite its seems logical answer it do not work propertly.Can anyone help me?